# 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have installed a lemp docker container w/ Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, Mariadb, & PHP 7.0, and have set up postfix and basic ssh capabilities that all work fine.  I have created a non-root user with sudo privileges (in the sudo group), but when I try to use sudo I get the error

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This happens for `sudo`, `sudo -s`, `sudo su`, etc.

I have gone into the `/etc/sudoers` file with visudo and added a line saying `me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` since some other places suggested this, but it hasn't fixed the issue.  Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: There's something wrong with your sudo config then as it's prompting for a password.  Can you add your sudo config and the command you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch the container with the tty enabled, `docker run -it ...`. That said, installing a web server, db, mail server, and ssh, on a single container are very much an anti-pattern in the docker world. This is treating docker as a lightweight vm rather than an immutable single application isolation tool.